# How can I create a javascript function that displays different values of a list every time I call it?

Tags: javascript, function

I want to have a javascript function ( which displays the elements of a list) that, every time that I call this function, it returns a different element of the list.So, I call it and displays the first element, than I call it again and displays the second one and so on...Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is :)

Comment: Please refer [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide necessary details

Comment: Yes there is using an array and picking a random element. People prefer it if you attempt what you're asking first though and post some code. There's already plenty of questions on SO about random array items

Comment: You can use `Math.random()` to grab a random value from the array - you could also pop of the first value from the array every time the function is called and return it to the caller.

Comment: It is called generator functions. May be usefull: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Answer (score 1):

Use a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), something like

```
function* nextInList(list) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < list.length)
    yield list[i++];
}

var gen = nextInList([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]);

gen.next().value // 10
gen.next().value // 9
// ...
```

Comment: As a note: this approach is not working in IE.  Nina's approach is cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the superb example of MDN for [Iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators) and use it for an array.

For every interval, the iterator is called with `next()` and then the value is checked. if done, clear the interval or display the property.

```js
function makeIterator(array) {
    var nextIndex = 0;
    return {
        next: function () {
            return nextIndex < array.length ?
                { value: array[nextIndex++], done: false } :
                { done: true };
        }
    };
}

var array = [1, 2, 5, 9, 10, 42, 43, 777],
    iterator = makeIterator(array),
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        var i = iterator.next();
        if (i.done) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            console.log(i.value);
        }                                // this value is for demo purpose
    }, 1000);                            // for a minute interval change to 60000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle your Array by using the function below And Then Display

```
function shuffle(array) {

  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

 // While there remain elements to shuffle...
 while (0 !== currentIndex) {

  // Pick a remaining element...
   randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
   currentIndex -= 1;

  // And swap it with the current element.
   temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
   array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
   array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}

 return array;
}
```